# Problem in algebra VIII

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So the problem is to solve the equation: $$ x^2-i=0$$

So I thought of factoring this out: $$ x^2-i=(x+\sqrt{i})(x-\sqrt{i})$$

Why? Because: $$(x+\sqrt{i})(x-\sqrt{i})=x^2+\sqrt{i}x-\sqrt{i}x-\sqrt{i}\sqrt{i}$$

We thus arrive at: $$(x+\sqrt{i})(x-\sqrt{i})=0$$
...which means the roots are positive square root of $i$ and negative square root of $i$. Am I correct?

Comment: @BalarkaSen This is the problem you sent in the chat room 'Mathematics'

Comment: Yes, you are.... **but** : aren't you suppose to express those square roots in some more or less "normal" form? Say, in rectangular or polar writing?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: In my opinion, you are not completely correct in your last line, since $positive$ and $negative$ have no meaning in $\mathbb C$. I also agree with DonAntonio's remark.

Comment: @DonAntonio What is rectangular and polar writing? (I heard of polar coordinates but I don't know what is, could you please provide me with a reference to an easy introductory text to rectangular and polar coordinates?)

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Let $\displaystyle x=a+ib\implies x^2=a^2-b^2+2abi=i$ where $a,b$ are real

Comparing the real & the imaginary parts, $\displaystyle a^2-b^2=0, 2ab=1$

$\displaystyle a^2+b^2=\sqrt{(a^2-b^2)^2+(2ab)^2}=\cdots$

Observe that $a,b$ have same parity

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt{i}=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}$, $-\sqrt{i}=-\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}$

Comment: Yes, I see my mistake.